# Elementor AJAX Popups

Tags: elementor

I would like to optimize my site, it has a lot of popups. Popups are loaded along with the main page (I mean standard Popups Elementor). Is it possible to load them asynchronously, via ajax (Elementor Support could not help, maybe someone has already solved this problem)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well, there is no built-in option in Elementor to load popups asynchronously, you can achieve this functionality but you need to have a solid understanding of JavaScript, AJAX, PHP, and the Elementor API. because it involves custom coding and modifications to your theme or plugin files.